# Explanation for GCC compiler optimisation's adverse performance effect?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, compiler-optimization

**Please note:** this question is *neither* about code quality, and ways to improve the code, *nor* about the (in)significance of the runtime differences. *It is* about GCC and why which compiler optimisation costs performance.

#### The program

The following code counts the number of Fibonacci primes up to `m`:

```cpp
int main() {
  unsigned int m = 500000000u;
  unsigned int i = 0u;
  unsigned int a = 1u; 
  unsigned int b = 1u; 
  unsigned int c = 1u;
  unsigned int count = 0u;

  while (a + b <= m) {
    for (i = 2u; i < a + b; ++i) {
      c = (a + b) % i;

      if (c == 0u) {
        i = a + b;
        // break;
      }
    }
    
    if (c != 0u) {
      count = count + 1u;
    } 
  
    a = a + b;
    b = a - b;
  }

  return count; // Just to "output" (and thus use) count
}
```

When compiled with `g++.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0` and no optimisations (`-O0`), the resulting binary executes (on my machine) in 1.9s. With `-O1` and `-O3` it takes 3.3s and 1.7s, respectively.

I've tried to make sense of the resulting binaries by looking at the assembly code ([godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/xPzaGK)) and the corresponding control-flow graph ([hex-rays.com/products/ida](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/)), but my assembler skills don't suffice.

#### Additional observations

1. An explicit `break` in the innermost `if` makes the `-O1` code fast again:

   ```cpp
   if (c == 0u) {
     i = a + b; // Not actually needed any more
     break;
   }
   ```
2. As does "inlining" the loop's progress expression:

   ```cpp
   for (i = 2u; i < a + b; ) { // No ++i any more
     c = (a + b) % i;

     if (c == 0u) {
       i = a + b;
       ++i;
     } else {
       ++i;
     }
   }
   ```

#### Questions

1. Which optimisation does/could explain the performance drop?
2. Is it possible to explain what triggers the optimisation in terms of the C++ code (i.e. without a deep understanding of GCC's internals)?
3. Similarly, is there a high-level explanation for why the alternatives (additional observations) apparently prevent the rogue optimisation?

Comment: I think it may be related to possible overflow in `i`. Note that when you want to end the loop you do `i = a + b;` but then the increment happens `++i` before the loop condition. What if `a + b == MAX_UINT`? If you move the `++i` to an `else` or even if you add a `i < a + b && !finished` control variable to the loop, you gain back the lost performance.

Comment: FWIW, compiling with `gcc -O1 -fno-if-conversion test.c` gives good performance back. No idea why...

Comment: Check assembly output of both options [your self](https://godbolt.org/z/GKrPfb) As you can see optimized version generates less CPU instructions and those instructions more optimal for current task. So this is why you can see huge performance impact. In the same time optimization is not free - i.e. you are speeding more time during compilation, as well as it may bring to unexpected issues. So you have to analyze result your self in any case.

Comment: @VictorGubin: But why the `-O2` is way slower than `-O0`? Certainly the optimized code is shorter and looks smarter, but it _is_ slower, hence the question.

Comment: I think this is your specific CPU related, i.e. some instructions are worst for you CPU model. You can try `-mtune=native -O2` and check then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing at play here are **loop-carried data dependencies**.

Look at machine code of the slow variant of the innermost loop. I'm showing `-O2` assembly here, `-O1` is less optimized, but has similar data dependencies overall:

```
.L4:
        xorl    %edx, %edx
        movl    %esi, %eax
        divl    %ecx
        testl   %edx, %edx
        cmove   %esi, %ecx
        addl    $1, %ecx
        cmpl    %ecx, %esi
        ja      .L4
```

See how the increment of the loop counter in `%ecx` depends on the previous instruction (the `cmov`), which in turn depends on the result of the division, which in turn depends on the previous value of loop counter.

Effectively there is a chain of data dependencies on computing the value in `%ecx` that spans the entire loop, and since the time to execute the loop dominates, the time to compute that chain decides the execution time of the program.

Adjusting the program to compute the number of divisions reveals that it executes 434044698 `div` instructions. Dividing the number of machine cycles taken by the program by this number gives 26 cycles in my case, which corresponds closely to latency of the `div` instruction plus about 3 or 4 cycles from the other instructions in the chain (the chain is `div`-`test`-`cmov`-`add`).

In contrast, the `-O3` code does not have this chain of dependencies, making it **throughput-bound** rather than **latency-bound**: the time to execute the `-O3` variant is determined by the time to compute 434044698 independent `div` instructions.

Finally, to give specific answers to your questions:

**1. Which optimisation does/could explain the performance drop?**

As another answer mentioned, this is if-conversion creating a loop-carried data dependency where originally there was a control dependency. Control dependencies may be costly too, when they correspond to unpredictable branches, but in this case the branch is easy to predict.

**2. Is it possible to explain what triggers the optimisation in terms of the C++ code (i.e. without a deep understanding of GCC's internals)?**

Perhaps you can imagine the optimization transforming the code to

```c
    for (i = 2u; i < a + b; ++i) {
      c = (a + b) % i;
      i = (c != 0) ? i : a + b; 
    }
```

Where the ternary operator is evaluated on the CPU such that new value of `i` is not known until `c` has been computed.

**3. Similarly, is there a high-level explanation for why the alternatives (additional observations) apparently prevent the rogue optimisation?**

In those variants the code is not eligible for if-conversion, so the problematic data dependency is not introduced.

Comment: I think your already excellent answer would be even better with a side by side comparison of the -O2 loop carried dependencies and the -O3 without the chain of dependencies. Perhaps a link to godbolt with both optimization levels would do.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in the `-fif-conversion` that instructs the compiler to do `CMOV` instead of `TEST/JZ` for some comparisons. And `CMOV` is known for being not so great in the general case.

There are two points in the disassembly, that I know of, affected by this flag:

First, the `if (c == 0u) { i = a + b; }` in line 13 is compiled to:

```
test   edx,edx //edx is c
cmove  ecx,esi //esi is (a + b), ecx is i
```

Second, the `if (c != 0u) { count = count + 1u; }` is compiled to

```
cmp    eax,0x1   //eax is c
sbb    r8d,0xffffffff //r8d is count, but what???
```

Nice trick! It is substracting `-1` to `count` but with carry, and the carry is only set if `c` is less than `1`, which being unsigned means `0`. Thus, if `eax` is 0 it substracts -1 to `count` but then substracts 1 again: it does not change. If `eax` is not 0, then it substracts `-1`, that increments the variable.

Now, this avoids branches, but at the cost of missing the obvious optimization that if `c == 0u` you could jump directly to the next `while` iteration. This one is so easy that it is even done in `-O0`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is **caused by the "conditional move" instruction (CMOVEcc)** that the compiler generates to replace branching when using `-O1` and `-O2`.

When using `-O0`, the statement `if (c == 0u)` is compiled to a jump:

```
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0
    jne     .L4
```

With `-O1` and `-O2`:

```
    test    edx, edx
    cmove   ecx, esi
```

while `-O3` produces a jump (similar to `-O0`):

```
    test    edx, edx
    je      .L5
```

[**There is a known bug in gcc**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56309) where "using conditional moves instead of compare and branch **result in almost 2x slower code**"

As **rodrigo** suggested in his comment, using the flag `-fno-if-conversion` tells gcc not to replace branching with conditional moves, hence preventing this performance issue.